# Custom Web API Conventions are not working with ODataController

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I am using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` (v6.5.0) for the Swagger documentation and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` (v8.2.3) in my `net7.0` project where I added custom Web Api Conventions class and using it in the controller. I am not understanding why this is not displaying required responses in the swagger ui.

Here is CustomWebApiConventions implementation:

```cs
public static class CustomWebApiConventions
{
    #region GET
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Get(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        params object[] p)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Find(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object id)
    { }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Post convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    #region POST
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Post(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object model)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Create(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object model)
    { }
    #endregion

    #region PUT
    /// <summary>
    /// Put convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status428PreconditionRequired)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Put(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Suffix)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object id,

        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object model)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Edit convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status428PreconditionRequired)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Edit(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Suffix)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object id,

        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object model)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status428PreconditionRequired)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Update(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Suffix)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object id,

        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Any)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object model)
    { }
    #endregion

    #region DELETE
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete convention.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status428PreconditionRequired)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Delete(
        [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Suffix)]
        [ApiConventionTypeMatch(ApiConventionTypeMatchBehavior.Any)]
        object id)
    { }
    #endregion
}
```

And the controller using CustomWebApiConventions as an ApiConventionsType attribute:

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion(1.0)]
[ApiConventionType(typeof(CustomWebApiConventions))]
public class MyController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<MyDto>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<MyDto> queryOptions)
    {
        // Implementation goes here.
        
        return Ok(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyDto>> Post([FromBody] CreateRequestParameter parameter)
    {
        // Create record

        return Ok(entity);
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyDto>> Update([FromRoute, BindRequired] Guid modelId, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<UpdateRequestParameter> parameter)
    {
        // Update entity here...

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```